# in my grid view i want to show a email without losing the formatting like bullet point or line breaks etc

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

```
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CreatedDate" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="CreatedDate"
                        DataFormatString="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}">
                        <ItemStyle  Wrap="false" Width="90px" />
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CreatedByUser" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="CreatedBy">
                        <ItemStyle  Wrap="false" Width="100px" />
                    </asp:BoundColumn>

                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Team" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="AssignedTeam">
                        <ItemStyle  Wrap="false" Width="150px"/>
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ExpectedDate" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="ExpectedDate"
                        DataFormatString="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy  HH:mm:ss}">
                        <ItemStyle  Wrap="false" Width="90px" />
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ClosedDate" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="ClosedDate">
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="false"  Width="130px"  />
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ClosedByUser" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="ClosedBy">
                        <ItemStyle  Wrap="false" Width="150px" />
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CloseReasonDescription" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="CloseReason">
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="false"  Width="100px"  />
                    </asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn   DataField="email" ReadOnly="True"  HeaderText="emailContent">
                       <ItemStyle Width="200px" >
                        </ItemStyle>
                   </asp:BoundColumn>                     
                </Columns> 
            </asp:DataGrid>
```

> but my email in the grid view is not dispalying the format. when i debug i could see the content of that column to be having formatting but it does not respect formatting when displaying

Answer (score 0):

added this style to column for which i want to retain the formatting

```
<style type="text/css">
   .formatCommentText
   {
    word-break:break-all;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
     width: 40%;
    }
</style>

<asp:BoundColumn   DataField="email" ReadOnly="True"  HeaderText="emailContent"> 
<ItemStyle CssClass="formatCommentText" Width="40%" >
    </ItemStyle> </asp:BoundColumn>
```